# Growth slower than the exponential

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a non-negative continuous function such that $f(0) = 0$.
Consider the function
$$F(t) := \int_0^t\int_0^sf(\tau)d\tau ds.$$

If $\lim_{t\to \infty}\dfrac{F(t)}{\exp(t)} = 0,$
is there anything I can say about the growth of $f$?

Comment: Your title is confusing, since your condition amounts to $ F $ growing slower than an exponential, not decaying faster than one.

Comment: @Starfall you are totally right. Fixed it.

Comment: Basically, you are looking for the growth of the second derivative of $F$. Unfortunately, $f$ could be really big during very short times without changing the growth of $F$.

Comment: @LL3.14, I got the same conclusion. There is nothing I can conclude. I do appreciate your comment.